# Reducing belly fat through home work outs like plank

Tags: bellyfat, planks

I Workout at home, doing push ups mostly. I even do a bit of jump rope, 1000 jumps per day. My biceps, triceps and chest have a good shape and are toned. But my belly has fat. How do I reduce my belly fat through home work out?  Does exercises like plank help me in reducing the belly fat? I know spot reduction is not possible. But will plank help me reduce those few extra kilos.

Comment: This question has been asked a hundred different ways on this site. The only thing that reduces fat is a negative energy balance (a caloric deficit). Exercise can contribute to this, but what you put in your mouth makes the biggest impact.

Answer (score 0):

Planks will not help reduce body fat.

As JustSnilloc wrote ....  creating a caloric deficit is the only way to get rid of body fat.

Nutrition comes first for fat loss.

Second is exercise.  What are you currently doing for exercise is not bad.  But is it ideal?  No.

At some point you should consider adding some heavier resistance training.  Check craigslist or facebook marketplace for a used set of power blocks or the box flex version of the same...  basically dumbbells and start doing resistance training.

Squat
Deadlift
Dumbbell Rows
Dumbbell Overhead Press
Dumbbell Floor Press
Lunge
etc

5-7 exercise with the power blocks or similar dumbbells.
3 sets of 8-12 reps
3 times per week

Add the jump rope and you will be off to a great start.

But you still have to be at a caloric deficit.